# How to iterate step with right shift in Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use right shift as the step argument in xrange?

Basically I'm trying to do this (pseudo-code)

```
for i in xrange(35926661, 0, _value_>>6):
    //logic
```

Comment: Please don't tell me you are using right shift as a division operator.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ In a sense, yes. It's not for anything important. Just sandboxing, playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

xrange always works by adding the third parameter. You cannot tell it to do something like a right shift instead.

A while loop will work, there may be better solutions but its hard to say without more information about what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom `xrange`-like function using a generator:

```
def lrange(a, b, f):
    num = a
    comp = operator.lt if (a < b) else operator.gt

    while comp(num, b):
        yield num
        num = f(num)
```

Then:

```
for x in lrange(35926661, 0, lambda x: x>>6):
    print(x)
```

#### http://codepad.org/0pYfWqSF

Comment: @JohnGiotta Note that `lrange` behaves almost identically to `xrange`, you can do `list(lrange(35926661, 0, lambda x: x>>6))` and that will give you `[35926661, 561354, 8771, 137, 2]`